# can't stop rec video

Tags: android, cwac-camera

I can't reproduce this bug consistently, but sometimes, when I try to take a video with the library, I just can't press stop. The button UI reacts but nothing happends, no logs, nothing.

All I can say is when I got this bug, if I finish the activity and try to reopen it I got a crash with this stack trace :

EDIT : way to reproduce the bug : 
Start a photo activity, take a photo (skipConfirm(), don't know if it's mandatory thought), start a video activity : start recording, can't stop the vidéo recording

```
Process: com.m360learning.android, PID: 9267


    java.lang.IllegalStateException: CameraDevice was already closed
                                                         at android.hardware.camera2.impl.CameraDeviceImpl.checkIfCameraClosedOrInError(CameraDeviceImpl.java:1997)
                                                         at android.hardware.camera2.impl.CameraDeviceImpl.createCaptureSessionInternal(CameraDeviceImpl.java:542)
                                                         at android.hardware.camera2.impl.CameraDeviceImpl.createCaptureSession(CameraDeviceImpl.java:476)
                                                         at com.commonsware.cwac.cam2.CameraTwoEngine$InitPreviewTransaction.onOpened(CameraTwoEngine.java:409)
                                                         at android.hardware.camera2.impl.CameraDeviceImpl$1.run(CameraDeviceImpl.java:134)
                                                         at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                         at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
```

second kind of crash (lauch videoActivity, start recording, back relaunch activity, can't start recording, back again, few seconds later : crash)

```
Process: com.m360learning.android, PID: 10912
                                                   java.lang.IllegalStateException
                                                       at android.media.MediaRecorder.stop(Native Method)
                                                       at com.commonsware.cwac.cam2.ClassicCameraEngine.onInfo(ClassicCameraEngine.java:364)
                                                       at android.media.MediaRecorder$EventHandler.handleMessage(MediaRecorder.java:1036)
                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Comment: There is not much I can do without a reproducible test case and details of the hardware that reproduces the problem.

Comment: this is a nexus 5 android 6 (hammered/hammered). I also am able to make it crash in other ways :  if I launch the video activity, launch video then back, then relaunch the activity : you can't launch the video no more

Comment: and few seconds later it crashes (I update my post with the stacktrace)

Comment: Is that second crash scenario fairly consistent? In other words, does it usually crash when you do that?

Comment: Yes the second scenario (I just found it), makes it crash every time

Comment: I updated the scenario thought, I forgot one step

Comment: OK, I am tracking the latter problem in [this issue](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-cam2/issues/155). Please subscribe to that issue if you want to be notified of changes in its status.

Comment: Ok I found a way to reproduce the fist bug, I update my post

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104558/discussion-between-renaud-favier-and-commonsware).

Comment: OK, I am tracking that one in [this issue](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-cam2/issues/156).